# PHP 7.2 fastcgi doesn't work on Ubuntu 18.04 server

Tags: apache2, php7, php-fpm, fastcgi

I've just installed LAMP on a Ubuntu 18.04 server and I can't get PHP fastcgi to work.

Here are my settings:

My fpm PHP file: `/etc/php/7.2/fpm/pool.d/sites.mydomain.conf`:

```
[sites.mydomain]
 ...
user = sites
group = sites
 ...
listen = /run/php/php7.2-fpm.sites.mydomain.sock
 ...
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
```

Then:

```
sudo service php7.2-fpm reload
sudo service php7.2-fpm restart
```

My virtual host file
`/etc/apache2/sites-available/sites.mydomain.conf`:

```
    ServerName sites.mydomain
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /srv/www/sites/html

    <IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
      AddHandler php7-fcgi-sites .php
      Action php7-fcgi-sites /php7-fcgi-sites
      Alias /php7-fcgi-sites /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7-fcgi-sites
     FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7-fcgi-sites -idle-timeout 60 -socket /var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sites.mydomain.sock -pass-header Authorization

      <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
        Require all granted
      </Directory>
    </IfModule>

    <Directory /srv/www/sites/html>
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      AllowOverride None
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

Then:

```
sudo a2enmod actions
sudo service apache2 restart
```

But PHP is not interpreted when running scripts, pages are displayed as plain text.

Can someone tells me what's wrong in my settings?

Note: I set it exactly the same way on my Ubuntu 16.04 server and it works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally there is no need to install the `libapache2-mod-fastcgi` package.
The trick takes place in the `etc/apache2/sites-available/sites.mydomain.conf` file (see my example above).
Replace the `<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>` part with

```
<FilesMatch "\.php$">
   SetHandler "proxy:unix:///var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sites.mydomain.sock|fcgi://sites/"
</FilesMatch>
```

and you're done.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Not sure if I'm doing something wrong, but using this solution does nothing for me. It doesnt return error, thats something, but apache doesnt change its behaviour. Whats more, I can enter bogus data into this line and my Moodle instalation would still work..

Comment: I have ubuntu server 18.04 and zentyal 6.1. On the first, your suggestion and the various guides https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Ubuntu_18.04&p=httpd&f=13 do not work while they do not work on the second. Any idea?

Answer (score 8):

I unfortunately took the advice of the answers here, which either incorrect, or a tangental.

After a little digging, i realised that the module in question (proxy_fcgi) is actually [part of the bionic apache2-bin package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/apache2-bin/filelist)

so all that was needed was:

```
a2enmod proxy_fcgi
```

Comment: In order to get it work with proxy_fcgi I also had to enable the php conf: `sudo a2enconf php7.2-fpm` 
but unfortunately my php configuration file /etc/php/7.2/fpm/pool.d/sites.mydomain.conf (see above  for more detail) is not taken into account. The process user is www-data instead of my username (ie: sites).

Comment: I finally got it to work by replacing the <IfModule> part with:   
`<FilesMatch "\.php$">
  SetHandler "proxy:unix:///var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sites.mydomain.sock|fcgi://sites/"
</FilesMatch>` in the apache vhost conf.

Answer (score 3):

So... I did some digging on this.

First, it seems that mod_fcgid is the free version of mod_fastcgi, but sends fewer requests per stream, so is slower.

But both seem to be fairly outdated, and it seems the libapache2-mod-fastcgi package was pulled from Debian for various reasons: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=835374

However, as of apache 2.4.10, it is best to use the mod_proxy_fcgi module with php fpm. https://serverfault.com/questions/783173/differences-between-mod-fastcgi-and-mod-proxy-fcgi

Hope this helps clear things up. Most php-fpm guides around don't seem to be updated for mod_proxy_fcgi use yet, so might be causing confusion.

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather, it could be that `libapache2-mod-fastcgi` package is not available for bionic yet. As such, there is no fastcgi module available for Apache2.

Comment: So what about the `libapache2-mod-fcgid` package ?
That's the one I've installed. It isn't supposed to replace the `libapache2-mod-fastcgi` package ?

Comment: Ok I got it. I've downloaded the fastcgi package here:

`wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/multiverse/liba/libapache-mod-fastcgi/libapache2-mod-fastcgi_2.4.7~0910052141-1.2_amd64.deb` 

then
 
`sudo dpkg -i <package name>  
sudo a2enmod fastcgi 
sudo service apache2 restart `

and now everything works fine.

But still, I'm dubious about 2 points:  

1) Is it safe to do it that way regarding Ubuntu updates and package dependencies ?  
2) FastCgi is widely used with Apache servers. Why Ubuntu removed it from its repositories without any other alternatives left ?

Comment: i advise against using this module manually. it crashes regularly on my machines.

Comment: I don't advise to use `libapache2-mod-fastcgi` module in Bionic or newer distro. Apache2 provides `mod_proxy_fcgi` module that proxies fcgi requests.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded from 17.10 to 18.04 and pages were just loading with the contents of the php file rather than rendering the page. All I had to do was update my `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/fastcgi.conf` file with the following:

```
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
  AddHandler php7-fcgi-sites .php
  Action php7-fcgi-sites /php7-fcgi-sites
  Alias /php7-fcgi-sites /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7-fcgi-sites
 FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7-fcgi-sites -idle-timeout 60 -socket /var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock -pass-header Authorization

  <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

## For Ubuntu 20-22 users:

### Purpose:

***Install fpm with sockets + fcgid module + apply user rights on requests per domain.***

### step 1: installation

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo systemctl stop apache2
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-fcgid
sudo apt-get install php8.1-fpm

# ubuntu 20 missing libs?!
sudo apt-get install php-mbstring
sudo apt-get install php-gd
```

### step 2: disable/enable modules

```
sudo a2dismod php* mpm_prerfork cgi cgid
sudo a2enmod mpm_event fcgid proxy_fcgi headers rewrite
# Ubuntu 20
sudo a2enconf php7.4-fpm
# Ubuntu 22
sudo a2enconf php8.1-fpm
```

### step 3: add configuration commands

***User: "john"***

***Domain: "mydomain.com"***

***(a). Apache FPM configuration***

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/mods-available/fcgid.conf
```

type:

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
  FcgidConnectTimeout 20
  AddType   application/x-httpd-php .php
  AddHandler    application/x-httpd-php .php
  <IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

***(b). FPM configuration***

```
# Ubuntu 20
sudo cp /etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/www.conf /etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/mydomain.com.conf
# Ubuntu 22
sudo cp /etc/php/8.1/fpm/pool.d/www.conf /etc/php/8.1/fpm/pool.d/mydomain.com.conf
```

change:

```
[www] -> [mydomain.com]
user = www-data -> user = john
group = www-data -> group = john
```

add or leave empty:

```
;;;;;;;;;;
; Memory ;
;;;;;;;;;;
php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 12M
php_admin_value[post_max_size] = 12M
php_admin_value[upload_max_filesize] = 12M
;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Settings ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;
php_value[user_ini.filename] = ".user.ini"
php_value[default_charset] = "UTF-8"
php_flag[short_open_tag] = Off
php_flag[display_errors] = On
php_flag[display_startup_errors] = On
php_flag[log_errors] = On
php_value[log_errors_max_len] = 1024
php_flag[report_memleaks] = On
php_flag[html_errors] = On
php_value[error_reporting] = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
php_flag[file_uploads] = On
php_value[max_file_uploads] = 20
php_flag[allow_url_fopen] = On
php_flag[allow_url_include] = Off
php_value[session.save_handler] = files
php_flag[session.use_strict_mode] = 1
php_flag[session.use_cookies] = 1
php_flag[session.use_only_cookies] = 1
; temporary disabled for step 5 system('whoami'); to run!
;php_admin_value[disable_functions] = exec,passthru,shell_exec,system
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Paths and Directories ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
php_admin_value[error_log] = "/var/www/mydomain.com/log/php_errors.log"
php_admin_value[open_basedir] = "/var/www/mydomain.com/"
php_admin_value[doc_root] = "/var/www/mydomain.com"
php_admin_value[sys_temp_dir] = "/var/www/mydomain.com/tmp"
php_admin_value[upload_tmp_dir] = "/var/www/mydomain.com/tmp"
php_admin_value[session.save_path] = "/var/www/mydomain.com/session"
php_admin_value[soap.wsdl_cache_dir] = "/var/www/mydomain.com/tmp"
php_admin_value[curl.cainfo] = "/var/www/mydomain.com/server/registry/cacert.pem"
```

`php_admin_value`, `php_admin_flag`: can't be changed by user

`php_value`, `php_flag`: can be changed by user

***(c). Create vhost***

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/mydomain.com.conf
```

type:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName mydomain.com.localhost
ServerAlias mydomain.com.localhost
ServerAdmin admin@mydomain.com

DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain.com

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
    FcgidConnectTimeout 20
    AddType   application/x-httpd-php .php
    AddHandler    application/x-httpd-php .php

    # Ubuntu 20
    ProxyPassMatch " ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$" "unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.mydomain.com.sock|fcgi://localhost/var/www/mydomain.com/"
    # Ubuntu 22
    ProxyPassMatch " ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$" "unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.mydomain.com.sock|fcgi://localhost/var/www/mydomain.com/"

    <Directory /var/www/mydomain.com/>
        Options +ExecCGI
        Options -Indexes
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
#        FRONT CONTROLLER PATTERN
#        RewriteEngine On
#        RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "!=/public_html/index.php"
#        RewriteRule "^(.*)$" "/public_html/index.php?$1" [NC,NE,L,PT,QSA]
    </Directory>
</IfModule>

# CPU usage limits 5s 10s
RLimitCPU 5 10
# memory limits to 10M 20M
RLimitMEM 10000000 20000000
# limit of forked processes 20 30
RLimitNPROC 20 30
LogLevel warn
ErrorLogFormat connection "[%t] New connection: [%{c}L] [ip: %a]"
ErrorLogFormat request "[%t] [%{c}L] New request: [%L] [pid %P] %F: %E"
ErrorLogFormat "[%t] [%{c}L] [%L] [%l] [pid %P] %F: %E: %M"
ErrorLog /var/www/mydomain.com/log/apache_error.log
CustomLog /var/www/mydomain.com/log/apache_access.log combined
ServerSignature Off
</VirtualHost>
```

***(d). Network***

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

type(*):

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   mydomain.com
127.0.1.1   aspire1.machine.com aspire1

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

create or edit file:

```
sudo nano /etc/localhost
```

type there(*):

```
aspire1
```

(*)replace `aspire1` with any short name you like.

### step 4: load vhost

```
sudo a2ensite mydomain.conf
```

### step 5: create domain files + permissions

```
sudo mkdir -p  /var/www/mydomain.com/public_html
sudo mkdir /var/www/mydomain.com/log/
sudo touch /var/www/mydomain.com/public_html/info.php
sudo nano /var/www/mydomain.com/public_html/info.php
```

at `info.php` type:

```
<?php

echo '<b>';
echo php_sapi_name();
echo '</b><br>';

printf("%s<br>", 'DOCUMENT_ROOT=<b>'.$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'</b>');

printf("%s", 'User=<b>');
system('whoami');
echo '</b><br>';

phpinfo();
```

Assign permissions:

```
sudo chown -R  john:john /var/www/mydomain.com
sudo find /var/www/mydomain.com -type d -name '*' -exec chmod 700 {} \;
sudo find /var/www/mydomain.com -type f -name '*' -exec chmod 600 {} \;
# open execute
sudo chmod 711 /var/www/mydomain.com
sudo chmod 711 /var/www/mydomain.com/public_html
```

### step 6: Ignition!

```
# Ubuntu 20
sudo service php7.4-fpm reload
sudo service php7.4-fpm restart
# Ubuntu 22
sudo service php8.1-fpm reload
sudo service php8.1-fpm restart
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

### step 7: cockpit!

Supposing you haven't enabled `rewrite` at the vhost file, open browser and type:

```
mydomain.localhost/public_html/info.php
```

### step 8: switch Apache configuration

***Let's switch from FPM to modphp:***

```
# Ubuntu 20
sudo a2disconf php7.4-fpm
sudo a2enmod php7.4
# Ubuntu 22
sudo a2disconf php8.1-fpm
sudo a2enmod php8.1
######
sudo a2dismod mpm_event
sudo a2dismod fcgid
sudo a2dismod proxy_fcgi
sudo a2enmod mpm_prefork
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

***Let's switch from modphp to FPM:***

```
# Ubuntu 20
sudo a2enconf php7.4-fpm
sudo a2dismod php7.4
# Ubuntu 22
sudo a2enconf php8.1-fpm
sudo a2dismod php8.1
######
sudo a2dismod mpm_prefork
sudo a2enmod mpm_event
sudo a2enmod fcgid
sudo a2enmod proxy_fcgi
# Ubuntu 20
sudo service php7.4-fpm reload
# Ubuntu 22
sudo service php8.1-fpm reload
######
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Good luck!

Ref.:

1. https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/how-to-install-and-configure-fastcgi-and-php-fpm-on-ubuntu-18-04/
2. https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/how-to-install-and-configure-fastcgi-and-php-fpm-on-debian-10/